# CSS Grid: Different Number of Columns depending on number of items

Tags: css

Before I start programming this, better make sure it's not possible in pure CSS.

I have a grid container:

```
.grid {
    height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-auto-rows: auto;
```

However the number of items in it could change as it's pulled from the database.

I would ideally prefer to alter the number of columns depending on the number of items. Maybe it could be achieved with grid-auto-columns?

E.g if I have 1-6 items, there is one column; if I have 7-12 items, two columns and if I have over 12 items add a third column.

Comment: Does using `flex` with `flex-wrap` enabled help

Comment: I don’t think it would work in this case as I wouldn’t have fine enough control (happy to be proven wrong) as with display:grid, if I have one or two columns, the container stays the same width but if I have 3 columns,  the container expands in width which is what I want. I think if I used flex, I wouldn’t be able to expand the container whilst wrapping.

Comment: Yes, it's the same basic problem when using `flex-wrap`. Just instead of having to change the `grid-template-columns` based on number of items, I would have to change the width/flex-basis of the container based on number of items (container is a flex-item). It also introduces some other quirks (I think the items inside the container are overflowing)

Comment: Set a css variable on the div when generating the backend code and use it to determine the number of cols

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below:

```css
.container {
  display:grid;
  gap:5px;
  border:1px solid;
  margin:5px;
}

.container > div {
  background:red;
  height:20px;
}

/* activate the 2nd column after 7 items*/
.container > div:first-child:nth-last-child(n+7) ~ :nth-child(2) {
  background: blue;
  grid-column: 2;
}

/* activate the 3rd column after 12 items*/
.container > div:first-child:nth-last-child(n+12) ~ :nth-child(3) {
  background: green;
  grid-column: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Some trickery there and it's not pretty code, but it works.